# SPD 2010 workflow - create multiple list items for each user in a people picker with multiple selections

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list with a title column and a people picker column that allows multiple selections. I want to create a workflow that will create a list entry in another list for each person in the people picker. The "create list item" will only create an entry for the first name in the people picker list.

I even tried using the "Extract substring from index of string" and set the "starting at" to "1" and then create list item from the variable and still only one list items was created in the other list.

I need an OOTB solution using SPD.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SPServices: PeoplePicker feature to find the number of users resolved in the field. And iterate to each of then to create new item using client object model.